# React - передача состояния между разными компонентами

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Есть основной компонент App

```
class App extends Component {
  сonstructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    AuthVisible: true,
  }
 }
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container-fluid">

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-4"><Logo /></div>
        <div className="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div className="col-lg-4"><Region /></div>
      </div>

      <Nav />

       <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-3"><Auth /></div>
        <div className="col-lg-6"><GlobalSearch /></div>
        <div className="col-lg-3"><MasterRightBanner /></div>
      </div>
</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Есть Компонент Auth, который импортирован в App

```
class Auth extends Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true,
      email: '',
      password: ''

    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    var tar = event.target.name;
    var val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({[tar]: val});


      }


  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({visible: false})
    alert('email : ' + this.state.email + "\\n" + 'password : ' + this.state.password);

  }

  render() {                            
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="authForm">ЛИЧНЫЙ КАБИНЕТ</div>
      <Form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} onChange= {this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Каким образом родительский компонент App может узнать, что в чилдрене Auth была нажата кнопка авторизации, и заменить этот компонент чем то другим? Например привет userName. Вопрос глобальный, не только по этой форме. Интересует решение без Redux.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В `App` объявить колбек:

   ```
   onSubmited = () => {
   }
   ```
2. Прокинуть в `Auth`:

   ```
    <div className="col-lg-3" onSubmited={this.onSubmited}><Auth /></div>
   ```
3. В `Auth` он будет в `props`. Поэтому в `handleSubmit` можете его вызвать:

   ```
   handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       this.setState({visible: false})
       alert('email : ' + this.state.email + "\\n" + 'password : ' +         this.state.password);
       if(this.props.onSubmited)
           this.props.onSubmited();
   }
   ```
4. В `onSubmited` вашего `App` что-нить делаете. Можете здесь поменять `state`. А на основании этого стейта в `render` выводить нужный компонент.